# Could "according to" be a synonym of "as agreed to"?

Tags: meaning, synonyms, syntactic-analysis

If I want to indicate agreement between both parts, it is correct to write a sentence like:

> I will be working from home tomorrow, according to John.

Usually, I would say to use "as agreed with" instead, but will the example be correct too?

Answer (score 2):

In your example case, no.  Your sentence means that John has told you you're working from home, and even implies that this has been imposed on you.  It might be possible to cook up an example in which they are interchangeable but "according to" generally means quoting someone else, often someone in a position of authority (or something: "according to my dictionary...").